# Amazon SES sending duplicate emails

Tags: duplicates, amazon-ses

I have switched to using Amazon SES to send our transactional alerts from our asp.net system and I'm getting calls that people are receiving duplicate emails.

I have confirmed that our program is only sending the email once to each user.

I received one of these duplicates exactly 5 minutes after the first email was sent, making me think it is some sort of retry issue.

Is there a way to configure/fix this issue?

If it makes any difference, I am using the AWS SDK in asp.net and calling the `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.SendEmail` call.

Comment: More info: I added some logging to show when the button was clicked and I'm getting two entries when there are thousands of emails to process. The page is timing out at the client side and seems to be reposting causing all the emails to be sent a second time.

Answer (score 6):

Amazon assigns a unique message ID to every email sent. Look in the full headers of the emails you received for an ID like the following:

0000012fea2d8375-85e23920-10cf-4d1b-b237-5dc13847b66c-000000@email.amazonses.com

If it is the same in both emails you got, then there is some sort of glitch between Amazon and the receiving SMTP server that is causing it to be resent.  If the ID is different between the 2 emails, then you are sending it twice.

Comment: Mitch: the two emails do have different ID's, but I changed the program to write the email address/subject line to the screen instead of calling "send", and it confirms that I'm only sending it once. I am using linq-to-sql and a foreach for sending the mails, wonder if I should add a .ToArray to the linq....?

Comment: Check your sending stats and email sending rate in SES dashboard